# Layout Resize when keyboard appear (ScrollView)

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to maintain the screen size in `Layout` when the keyboard appears, my idea is obtain the next in both cases (with or without keyboard):

```
|-----------------|
|      image      |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|    center lay   |
|                 |
|-----------------|
|                 |
|      image      |
|-----------------|
```

But in the center layout I have some `EditText` and when the soft KeyBoard appear, the center layout reduce its height and is shorter, causing the first `EditText` sticking to the picture above. I tried several forms, for example with a `RelativeLayout` align the images at the top and bottom, but when the keyboard appears hide the center layout and causes a horrible effect.

This is my code by now,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_iv_points_top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_et_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_edit_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_edit_margin_right"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/login_et_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_et_pass"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_edit_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_edit_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_edit_pass_margin_top"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/login_et_pass"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_bt_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_button_height"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/login_button_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_button_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_button_margin_top"
                android:background="@drawable/bt_selectable_degraded_style"
                android:text="@string/login_bt_access"
                android:textColor="@color/bt_text_color" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/login_tv_forgot_pass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_forgot_margin_top"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:onClick="registerForgotClick"
                android:text="@string/login_tv_forgot_pass"
                android:textColorLink="@color/company_color" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/login_iv_points_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it? I'm having the same issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` on the activity node of your Android Manifest. The keyboard will then pop over the content.

Comment: But with this option I don´t have ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in activity inside manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Have the same result that I comment to @Esteam.

Answer (score 0):

If you will remove windowSoftInputMode from manifest you will loss your scrolling so if you have a static image i mean from drawable resource than try this getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);