# Button needs to be on the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

Without Scrollview, Button is on the bottom on the screen, which is the desired result. But as soon as I add the Scrollview, the button is not at the bottom of the screen anymore.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/create_account_view">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollview_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:lines="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Then why you are using a ScrollView? Are there any more elements?

Comment: The `RelativeLayout`'s width is overridden with `wrap_content` as it is inside a `ScrollView`.

Comment: put  your button outside of the scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another attribute to `ScrollView`:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

This way `ScrollView` height will respect child's `android:layout_height="match_parent"` attribute

Comment: Sure, but now the button's height is stretched instead of "wrap content"

Comment: Are you sure? Is `RelativeLayout`'s `android:layout_height` attribute set to `match_parent` and `Button`'s `android:layout_height` attribute set to `wrap_content`?. I tested your layout with this parameter and it is working fine.

Comment: You're right, I was using android:layout_below. But now when the keyboard shows up, the button goes up because the scrollview is the height of the screen minus the keyboard. I don't want that, you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978581/layout-resize-when-keyboard-appear-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/create_account_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1">


</ScrollView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the scroll view, just add the following attribute to your scroll view.

```
    android:fillViewport="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the scrolling view behavior to the scroll view

```
app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

and add the code to button xml file

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
```